# proper function signature for parametrised function

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to write the signature for a function that maps a vector to a scalar with some parameters (e.g. a neuron in a neural network). Intuitively, I would write something like
$$\mathrm{neuron}_f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : \boldsymbol{x} \mapsto y = \mathrm{neuron}_f(\boldsymbol{x} \;;\; \boldsymbol{w}) = f(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})$$
where $f$ is some activation function and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

Is this correct, or should I rather write $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ or something completely different?

PS: I am sorry if my terminology happens to be incorrect. I have barely an idea what I am talking about (or whether terminology would even exist for this type of function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\operatorname{neuron}_f: ℝ^n \to ℝ$ and define it by $x \mapsto f(w ⋅ x)$, the problem is that it is not clear what is $w$ and where it came from. If it is a parameter, it should be denoted the same way as $f$: $\operatorname{neuron}_{f, w}$.

Of course now you have all these objects:

- For every $f ∈ F$ (where $f$ is the family of admissibe functions) and $w ∈ ℝ^n$ you have $\operatorname{neuron}_{f, w}: ℝ^n \to ℝ$ defined by $\operatorname{neuron}_{f, w}(x) = f(w ⋅ x)$.

  For every $f ∈ F$ you have the map $\operatorname{neuron}_f: ℝ^n × ℝ^n \to ℝ$ defined by $\operatorname{neuron}_f(w, x) = \operatorname{neuron}_{f, w}(x) = f(w ⋅ x)$. Of course it may be defined with different order of arguments and you may use ; to separate the primary variable $x$ from the other parameters: $\operatorname{neuron}_f(x; w) = \operatorname{neuron}_{f, w}(x) = f(w ⋅ x)$.

  You have also the map $\operatorname{neuron}: F × ℝ^n × ℝ^n \to ℝ$ defined by $\operatorname{neuron}(f, w, x) = \operatorname{neuron}_f(w, x)$ or $\operatorname{neuron}: ℝ^n × ℝ^n × F\to ℝ$ defined by $\operatorname{neuron}(x; w, f) = \operatorname{neuron}_f(x; w)$.

You may use different variant depending on your use case, but you should be consistent.

Comment: Does this mean that the full signature would then look something like this?
$$\mathrm{neuron}_f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : \boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{w} \mapsto a = f(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})$$

Comment: Yes, the signature would look like this.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of parameterisable functions is to emphasise that some arguments to the function actually shape the function that you would eventually be interested in. I have little knowledge about notation for partial function application, but couldn't a parameterised function be defined, using something like:

$$F : (Z \times X \to Y) \times Z \to (X \to Y) : (f, z) \mapsto F(f, z) = (x \mapsto f(z, x))$$

and then

$$\mathrm{neuron}_f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : \boldsymbol{x} \mapsto y = \mathrm{neuron}_f(\boldsymbol{x} \;;\; \boldsymbol{w}) = F\big(f, F(\boldsymbol{w}, \mathrm{neuron})\big)$$

where

$$\mathrm{neuron} : (\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : (f, \boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{x}) \mapsto y = f(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})$$

I am aware that this might not be the most practical solution, but could be useful!?